# Google Maps link with long and lat, masked with location text

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I am wanting to build a link to google maps reading the long and lat values from the database.

At the moment I have this:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=51.50335,-0.227721
```

Although when you view this google displays the long and lat in the search box.

Is it possible to hide this in the URL so that google reads the long and lat and displays the locaiton on the map form the long and lat but then displays the actualy location/address in the search box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ll` instead of `q`.

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=51.50335,-0.227721
```

I found it on the [Google Map Parameters](http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters) page of Mapki.

I can add a valid search to the query string and it will still show the location specified by `ll`. This does not center the map on Boulder, CO:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=51.50335,-0.227721&q=Boulder,CO
```